# android map view with button on pin

Tags: android, button, android-mapview

In my iphone application I have a `MapView` that has pins. When you tap on a pin you see a title and a `Button` that opens a detail view of that item. Now I'm making the same application in `Android` and I would like to do the same in `Android's MapView`.

Can anyone instruct me how can I place a pin that has a title and a `Button`?

Answer (score 1):

please consider using this open source library: [android mapview balloons](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons). It has all the functionality you need.